# Automate root ssh scripts

Tags: debian, scripting, root

We require to be able to run some script as root from nothing other than an SSH login.

IE, we have root and password, and we need to perform a script action on a bunch of servers.

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: Not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for Cluster SSH or Parallel SSH (pssh), I guess that's what you want to do.

Comment: I actually used an SSH2 lib plus script, worked very well and simple which is what we needed, not PSSH blah blah.

Comment: @JoshuaD'Alton: So, you come back after 18 months to tell us you disliked an answer to a barely-understandable question where you conveniently ignored requests for clarifications? Please, don't bother next time.

Answer (score -1):

Password login as `root` is not a good idea. Make yourself familiar with public key authentication with SSH.